# VBA, AppActivate Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy my pdf to excel using Send keys.
However I am getting a compile error at my `SecondStep` sub

```
Sub StartAdobe()

Dim AdobeApp As String
Dim AdobeFile As String
Dim StartAdobe

AdobeApp = "location of adobe reader"
AdobeFile = "file location"

StartAdobe = Shell("" & AdobeApp & " " & AdobeFile & "", 1)

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "FirstStep"

End Sub

Private Sub FirstStep()

SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "SecondStep"



   End Sub

    Private Sub SecondStep()

    Workbooks("testy").Activate
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

    Range("A1").Activate
    SendKeys ("^v")

    End Sub
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Everything works well prior to secondsub.

Comment: What are you trying to do here `Workbooks("testy").Activate.AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"`? This syntax is wrong. At least there should be a line break between `.Activate` and `AppActivate  "Microsoft Excel"`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it but still same error

Comment: Do you have Acrobat X or Standard or Pro? These come with VBA libraries that may help you more effeciently with this process.

Comment: Since your edit I don't get compile errors anymore.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman its just standard reader 11.0 .   @fonz, I am no longer getting a compiler error but now a `invaled procedure call or argument` on the app activate line.

Comment: Activate Excel before you activate the workbook?

Comment: @Chronocidal get the same error :(

Comment: Ah - `AppActivate` takes a Window/Application caption.  Try `AppActivate Workbooks("testy").Application.Caption` instead

Comment: @Chronocidal , very interesting! I no longer get the error! but all the pdf stuff pastes into my VBA terminal lol, just above my code. very odd.

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Paste` instead of `SendKeys`?

Comment: @Chronocidal , get an error on that, but I only replaced the `SendKeys ("^V")` with your recommendation .   "Object doesnt support this property or method."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the follwoing code will work

```
Private Sub SecondStep()

    AppActivate Application.Caption
    Workbooks("testy").Activate

    Range("A1").Activate
    SendKeys ("^v")

End Sub
```

Comment: I find this just pastes whatever I have currently copied to my VBA terminal, it also goes to my workbook but nothing is pasted in here.

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve with the code but it will activate Excel, then activate the workbook "testy" and cell A1. AND then it will send Ctrl-V to the keyboard which means that everything gets pasted into Excel whatever is in the clipboard. That's what you coded. I just fixed more or less the syntax.

Comment: I want to copy my pdf into excel, thats it really

Comment: But then you need to copy your PDF to the clipboard first what I think you are trying to do with the FirstStep. And FirstStep is probably not working. It might be better to follow Scott's advice to use the libraries that come with Adobe. I just saw that you probaly copied the code from somewhere [else](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/380573-pdf-excel-data-copy.html)

Comment: yes i did copy from there. I couldnt get it working, ill keep trying.

Comment: Code is working for me although I really would not use it because too many things can go wrong with sendkeys

Comment: If you're using Excel anyway, why select `Range("A1")` and `SendKeys` for [Ctrl]+[V]?  Just `Range("A1").Paste`...

Answer (score 0):

`AppActivate` accepts the title/caption of the window/application. (NOT the name of the Application.)  After you open the file, use `AppActivate Dir(AdobeFile)` to activate the window.

This is because if your `AdobeFile = "C:\Temp\Some PDF.pdf"` then your Adobe window will have the title "Some PDF.pdf - Adobe Reader" or "Some PDF.pdf - Adobe Acrobat", and `Dir(AdobeFile)` will be "Some PDF.pdf".  Then, `AppActivate "Some PDF.pdf"` will activate a window with a title that *starts* with "Some PDF.pdf" - or, throw an error if there isn't one.

```
Sub StartAdobe()
    Dim AdobeApp As String
    Dim AdobeFile As String
    Dim StartAdobe

    AdobeApp = "location of adobe reader"
    AdobeFile = "file location"

    StartAdobe = Shell("" & AdobeApp & " " & AdobeFile & "", 1)

    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now()+TimeSerial(0,0,10)
    DoEvents

    On Error GoTo NoFile

    AppActivate Dir(AdobeFile)
    SendKeys ("^a")
    SendKeys ("^c")

    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
    DoEvents

    AppActivate Workbooks("testy").Application.Caption

    'ALWAYS qualify your Ranges!
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Paste 'No need to SendKeys here!

    Exit Sub
NoFile:
    If MsgBox(AdobeFile & " could not be identified", vbCritical + vbAbortRetryIgnore) = vbRetry Then Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: I get your error message, but the pdf actually opens and highlights everything.